# How to handle ListPicker SelectionChanged event properly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, selectionchanged, listpicker

Good day, everybody. I have the following problem:

I have a listpicker with the x:Name="Backgroundlist" declared in XAML and it works fine.

Its items are declared as follows:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Backgroundlist.Items.Add("photo");
    Backgroundlist.Items.Add("Bing");               
}
```

However, the following code does not do its job (i.e. it doesn't show the MessageBox):

```
private void Backgroundlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Backgroundlist.SelectedItem.Equals("photo"))
    {   
        MessageBox.Show("photo");
    }
    if (Backgroundlist.SelectedItem.Equals("Bing"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bing");
    }
}
```

What seems to be the problem? Thanks!

P.S. I do not get an exception

Comment: `the following code does not do its job` do you get an exception?

Comment: Dear PoweredByOrange, Thanks for the prompt reply)
No, I do not get an exception.

Comment: What is `SelectedItem`'s type when SelectionChanged is called?

Comment: I'm greatly sorry, I'm a newbie to c# and I don't quite understand your question. Could you please be so kind as to explain what you mean in a broader interpretation? Thamks for your understanding))

Comment: Sure. Set a break point on line `if (Backgroundlist.SelectedItem.Equals("photo"))`. Then hover your mouse over `SelectedItem` and tell me what it says.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and understanding) It says 'object ListPicker.SelectedItem'

Comment: So does it have the value "photo" or "Bing"? Have you tried the `SelectedValue` property?

Comment: Nope. How should I do that?

Comment: Change `Backgroundlist.SelectedItem` to `Backgroundlist.SelectedValue.ToString.Equals`

Comment: Ehm(((

Error 2 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no extension method 'SelectedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Итак, будем учить тебя дебажить:

1 выбираешь нужную строчку и на клаве тыкаешь F9, во время выполнения кода там случится чудо-остановка можно будет посмотреть значения переменных

2 выделяешь этот текст "Backgroundlist.SelectedItem.Equals("photo")", кликаешь по нему правой кнопкой мыши, а там Add Watch. В специальном окошке появится значение (скорее всего false)

3 Так же советую посмотреть, что есть в переменной e (event args), и использовать её для построения условия.

Comment: I have tried your code, and it works correctly. Make sure that the `SelectionChanged` event of ListPicker is set to `Backgroundlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Dear, anderZubi. I made sure. Still no progress

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So here's the deal. As well I had to declare a `SelectionChanged="Picker"` in XAML. Here's the full code that works:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Backgroundlist" Header="Background" SelectionChanged="Picker" ExpansionMode="FullscreenOnly" />

public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Backgroundlist.Items.Add("photo");
            Backgroundlist.Items.Add("Bing");
        }

        private void Picker(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = sender as ListPicker;
            MessageBox.Show(picker.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
```

Everything turned out to be very primitive in the end)